# 'Control+t' not detected in emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, keyboard, gtk, archlinux

This article is about the keyboard key combination 'Control + t' (smallcase 't') and emacs.

This problem is exclusive to the gui version and does not come up while using the terminal.

I am using **Wayland**

1. Control+t : The cursor just blinks and nothing happens.

   - C-h k + C-t (Control+h and k followed by Control + t) : Nothing shows up.
   - C-h k + C-S-t : Works. Shows this

`'C-t (translated from C-S-t) runs the command transpose-chars (found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function...'`

Note **Translated from C-S-t**

This basically means that Control-t is getting eaten up somewhere in the process.

Some more info and curious things -

1. Control+t and terminals -

   1. Works in Kitty and termite - Detected by wev ; C-t 'tranpose-chars' in emacs-mode (bindkey -e in zsh) works
   2. Does not work in konsole   - Detected by wev ;  C-t 'tranpose-chars' in emacs-mode (bindkey -e in zsh) **does not** work.
2. wev output -

```
    [14:     wl_keyboard] key: serial: 5101; time: 10021865; key: 66; state: 1 (pressed)
                      sym: Control_L    (65507), utf8: ''

    [14:     wl_keyboard] modifiers: serial: 0; group: 0
                          depressed: 00000004: Control 
                          latched: 00000000
                          locked: 00000000
    
    [14:     wl_keyboard] key: serial: 5103; time: 10022192; key: 28; state: 1 (pressed)
                          sym: t (116), utf8: ''
```

3. Emacsclient -t (emacs client on terminal and tty)
   Works.

`` C-t runs the command transpose-chars (found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'. ``

4. Firefox and Chrome is able to detect the keypresses. Tested on https://keyboardchecker.com/

What do I need?

1. I need to understand why this is happening.
2. The solution to the same.

And I need your help.

TODO:

1. Need to check the same in X11 and then report.

[Update]
The same problem persists in X11. Again, Control+Shift+t works but not Control+t

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general Linux usage issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: I did that. Thanks.

Comment: My first thought was the classic "window manager eating that key sequence" issue, but that doesn't explain why other programs are seeing it (unless your WM is doing this conditionally).  I guess `wev` is the Wayland equivalent of `xev` ?  Under X11 did you test `xev` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Same results. It is the equivalent of xev